# does mobile position affects carrier signal strength?

Tags: antenna

after purchasing my directional wifi antenna (that should be poaitioned vertically) a thought came to my mind-
does mobile direction affects signal steength or not.

how the small signal receiver antenna is positioned in mobile phones (android,iphone)? does it matters if i hold mobile vertically or horizontally, when i want to increase signal strength?

also,does it matter if i hold mobile toughly with both hands (thus,covering the area with my body), does that cause any noticeable signal loss?

Comment: Please capitalise your title and questions - first word of sentence,  proper nouns (names and brand names) and "I" - for legibility and credibility.

Comment: Our hands are near quarterwave thickness for WiFi, assuming Er is 4.

Comment: Antenna radiation patterns are affected by almost everything to a lesser or greater degree.  In marginal signal situations the placement of your body in relation to your phone may cause loss of conectivity.

Answer (score 1):

> how the small signal receiver antenna is positioned in mobile phones
>   (android,iphone)? does it matters if i hold mobile vertically or
>   horizontally, when i want to increase signal strength?

No. For normal usage, you can think of the antenna as omni-directional.

> also,does it matter if i hold mobile toughly with both hands
>   (thus,covering the area with my body), does that cause any noticeable
>   signal loss?

Again no. Your body will not attenuate the signal noticeably. However, you will typically notice a signal loss when you step inside a elevator/lift, also known as the 'Faraday Cage Effect'

Comment: "Faraday cage" not "*Faraday's*".

Answer (score 1):

### does mobile position affects carrier signal strength?

Yes.

> how the small signal receiver antenna is positioned in mobile phones (android,iphone)?

usually, there's even multiple antennas, and they're typically spread out all over the case.

> does it matters if i hold mobile vertically or horizontally, when i want to increase signal strength?

In any given moment, you'll receive a sum of waves that is linearly polarized in an arbitrary direction – if you got a dominant line of sight to the base station, probably vertically, but as soon as there's more than one path, you cannot rely on that.

So, the polarization you receive is random, but it would be best if you rotate your receive antenna to have the same orientation.

Also, the mobile device has potentially multiple antennas for that exact reason: make sure at least one works, and if possible, take the best antenna, or even better, combine receive signals so that you get best possible reception.

> also,does it matter if i hold mobile toughly with both hands (thus,covering the area with my body), does that cause any noticeable signal loss?

Well, yes, you're a microwave-absorbing piece of human flesh.

But your hand isn't very thick, so the energy absorbed by the hands isn't going to be very much.

But: Hands in proximity to antenna will detune that antenna, but then again, we must assume that mobiles are built with that effect in mind, considering they're usually held in hands close to heads (which indeed absorb pretty well).